# How to make make navbar responsive, using a template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using a colorlib template called faithful: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/faithful/

Basically I changed the css and the navbar to a horizontal one, the problem is when I view it in mobile, it doesn't work

This is what I did to change the navbar to a horizontal one

```
<div class="site-navbar-wrap js-site-navbar bg-white">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="site-navbar bg-light">
      <div class="py-1">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-2">
        <a class="d-block" href="index.html" rel="home"><img class="d-block" src="images/company_logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="navbar-default" id="menu">
                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle fa" data-toggle="dropdown" href="about.html" >About Us<span></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="about.html">Our Company</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html#section1">Team</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html#section2">Goals</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html#section3">Location</a></li> 
                    </ul> 
                  <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>

                  </li>
                  <li><a href="merch.html">Merchandise</a></li>
                  <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the navbar to work on mobile (showing a button on the right)

I tried everything I could but it still doesn't work and I've already finished the design of the website, I just really need to change the navbar.

Comment: Did you include the javascript?

Comment: I didn't, I don't know what to do really since I'm fairly new to bootstrap. Would you like me to send the zip file of what I made?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ check out this link on how to make responsive navbars.

Comment: I've been trying to use that, its just that the template I'm using is making it hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">

  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav"
    aria-controls="basicExampleNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="basicExampleNav">

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our company</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">team</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">goals</a>
      </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">location</a>
      </li>


      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">products</a>
      </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">merchandise</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you can modify and use this

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! I just have to fix some of the other code

Comment: A quick follow up question, how do I make the button go to the right side of the screen when it is in viewed in mobile?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GqJBUle Here's how it looks like + the code snippet

Comment: the float-xs-right class in the button shall correct it